# How to check for Hash value in an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, key-value, hashset

Heres my set up

```
project_JSON = JSON.parse

teamList = Array.new

project = Hash.new()
project["Assignee Name"] = issue["fields"]["assignee"]["displayName"]
project["Amount of Issues"] = 0

if !teamList.include?(issue["fields"]["assignee"]["displayName"])
    project_JSON.each do |x|
        project["Amount of Issues"] += 1
        teamList.push(project)
end
```

Im having trouble with this line.

```
if !teamList.include?(issue["fields"]["assignee"]["displayName"])
```

It always returns true even after the `.push`. I want to make an array of my team members and list how many times their name appears in my JSON. What am I doing wrong and how do I dynamically refer to a hash value in an if statement(thats where I think its wrong because if I am saying `.include?(issue["fields"]["assignee"]["displayName"])` wrong then its nil and the if statement will always be true)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `teamList` is an empty array, so it does not `include?` anything, it will always return `false`. Now because you are using `!` operator it always returns true.

**EDIT**

If understood it right, you have to loop through the array checking each element for the value specified.

Below is a way to do it, mind you I replaced keys for symbols as it's a good practice in Ruby:

```
issue = {
    :fields => {
        :assignee => {
            :displayName => 'tiago'
        }
    }
}

teamList = Array.new

def teamList.has_assignee?(assignee)
    self.each do |e|
        return e[:assignee] == assignee
    end
    false
end


project = Hash.new
project[:assigneeName] = issue[:fields][:assignee][:displayName]
project[:amountOfIssues] = 0 

teamList.push(project) unless teamList.has_assignee? issue[:fields][:assignee][:dsiplayName] 
teamList.push(project) unless teamList.has_assignee? issue[:fields][:assignee][:dsiplayName] 


puts teamList.inspect # only one object here
```

As Sergio pointed out you could use `.detect`

```
def teamList.has_assignee?(assignee)
        self.detect { |e| e[:assigneeName] == assignee }
end
```

Comment: then it pushes the hashset to the teamList array which gives the if statement something to compare to and even then it returns true; thats where my problem lies

Comment: @EXC3ll3NTrhyTHM I have edited my answer, since I don't know your dataset I had to create the issue object

Comment: better to use `.detect` to implement `has_assignee?`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks for pointing out `.detect`  taking a look at Enumerable class, `.any?` could also be used, in fact it's a better fit since it returns a boolean

Comment: Or maybe not `.detect` returns as soon as the block returns true

Comment: @Tiago: right, `any?`. Stupid me. Always forgetting this one :)

Comment: No _need_ to give me credit in a P.S. Fix the main code. :)